# Making a variable in React available to external html file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am setting an ecommerce where the credit card data is added to the front end via an iframe. Part of the payment process includes generating a JWT which will be used by the iframe  to clear the credit card amount and other specific details about the transaction.

My problem here is that the actual JWT will be generated in React and I need somehow to communicate this piece of information with the script running on the html file inside the iframe, which communicates with the payment service.

I've been reading about this and found some useful information about adding custom environment variables with Create React App, which I used.

My question tough is that the documentation in Create React App describes two kind of ways to do this, depending on if the variable is needed at run time or build time(https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/)

Due to my lack of knowledge about the issue, I dont really know which approach is the right for me, to be able to send the JWT.

the iframe contains the following code besides some basic html for the form.

```
 <script> 
  (function() {
   var st = SecureTrading({  
    jwt: "INSERT JWT HERE"

    });  
   st.Components(); 
  })(); 
 </script>
```

Comment: (**Not Possible**) but without reading the content of your post, if I were to comment, you cannot bring any of the variables inside the React App outside unless (**First Solution**) you do it from inside by using `window.VarName` and that way you will be able to access the `VarName` from outside. Again, this causes Global Scope pollution. Is this what you're expecting? I can write an answer on this with an example, if this helps. (**Second Solution**) The other way is to use `localStorage` and get the value from `localStorage`. This you can do it in another page separately too! Does this help?

Comment: Yes, I do realise what you mention about global scope pollution, unfortunately I cannot come up to any other solution for this,as it is mandatory to have the code above in the iframe and it is also mandatory to have them communicate somehow to pass some information

Comment: Thank you, maybe using localStorage is a cleaner solution!!

Comment: And reading the question, irrespective of whether you use React or not, the JWT is commonly (not talking about good practice) stored in the `localStorage` so it's easily accessible. So I would suggest the second solution, which I told above.

Comment: Can I write an answer using `localStorage`?

Comment: sure,all constructive input is welcome.

Comment: Done. Check it out with a demo too! 

Answer (score 0):

In simple words, it's **Not Possible**.

**First Solution**

You cannot bring any of the variables inside the React App outside unless you do it from inside by using `window.VarName` and that way you will be able to access the `VarName` from outside. Again, there are two concerns here.

1. This causes Global Scope pollution.
2. How would you determine or know if the variable is set?

Chucking out this solution, but still it might work.

**Second Solution** (Most common and works)

The other way is to use `localStorage` and get the value from `localStorage`. This you can do it in another page separately too!  What you can do is, something like the below code after an AJAX call is made:

```js
  // Call the authentication service from the front end.
  AuthUser(Username, Password, (res, err) => {
    // If the request was an error, add an error state.
    if (err) {
      this.setState({ Error: res.response.data.Message });
    } else {
      // If there's no errors, further check if it's 200.
      if (res.status === 200) {
        // We need a JWT to be returned from the server.
        // The res.data holds both Message and JWT. We need the JWT.
        // Decode the JWT and store it in the state.
        DecodeJWT(res.data.JWT, data =>
          // Here, data.data will have the decoded data.
          this.setState({ Data: data.data })
          );
        // Now to persist the login after refresh, store in localStorage.
        // Check if localStorage support is there.
        if (typeof Storage !== "undefined") {
          // Set the JWT to the localStorage.
          localStorage.setItem("JWT", res.data.JWT);
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

I wrote an article about this from the basics and the part 4, I explain about JWT and storing in `localStorage`. Check out [Creating a full-stack MERN app using JWT authentication: Part 4](https://blog.logrocket.com/mern-app-jwt-authentication-part-4/) for more details.

Complete code and demo: [GitHub - praveenscience/JWT-MERN-FullStack: Creating a full-stack MERN app using JWT authentication](https://github.com/praveenscience/JWT-MERN-FullStack)